# How to shift an image in Scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-image

I'm trying to translate an image using the following code.

```
im = io.imread("path/to/my/image.jpg")
shift_image = scipy.ndimage.shift(im, np.array([1, 2]))
```

I'm using `skimage` to read the image.

I get the following error

```
RuntimeError: sequence argument must have length equal to input rank
```

Comment: What is  `im.shape`? If it's an RGB image, there's the third dimension for channel.

Comment: Yep, this ended up being the bug! I thought since the package is called `ndimage`, it would apply the shift for all channels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name `ndimage` (with "n-dimensional" in it) suggests that the package is not going to assume that images are two dimensional, and that any other dimension means something else. After all, 3D images (MRI) are a thing. So in effect, it operates with an abstract n-dimensional array. For an two-dimensional RGB image, the shape is `(height, width, 3)` because of the three color channels. So the shift would be `[1, 2, 0]`.